# Locking Desktop just Like Windows

Tags: fedora, windows, desktop, screen-lock

Whenever I am at work, I would like to lock the computer so my desktop isn't accessible to others. In windows it's trivial, press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key. 
Is there something similar available in Linux, particularly Fedora.

Comment: In many window managers, screen lock is available by mouse click from a drop-down context menu in the dock.

Comment: Which Fedora release and desktop? The answer depends.

Answer (score 3):

This varies depending on desktop environment. In Gnome and KDE, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> by default.

Comment: On my system, it brings up the option to "Shutdown", "Logout", "Hibernate" etc.
However, I don't see any option that matches the lock.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz - That's what Ctrl+Alt+delete does on my gnome system...

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Does ctrl+L work?

Comment: CTRL+L also does not work. In fact, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz - This link may be helpful for Gnome 3: http://askubuntu.com/a/122776